# Index large table best for performance Row or column Index

Tags: sql, indexing, datatables, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

I'm working with my first Azure sql db and have a very large table in rows and columns

The table in question has data from 2019 - 2020 and is around 22million rows
Pending batch load 2021 will catch it up to date and will be around 32million records

There are 350 columns in this table (So very wide)

On the daily load once the 2021 batch load is complete will be around 50,000 records per day

I want to improve the queries against this table to decrease the load times into PBI import

Row indexes will possibly be out of date straight away once the daily loads take place.

1. If I'm only ever subsetting this data in views for PBI to import on a couple of columns, is a columnStore index the way to go? Example

> Where  Description IN  ('Foo'
> ,'Bar'
> )
> AND Date > Dateadd(Month, -12,  '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000')

2. If I add a columnstore index will I need to refresh this after the 2021 load
3. Do I need to include all 350 columns? this will cause an increase in storage I guess.

Thanks in advance
It's more on best practices on the type of an Index when dealing with wide and large tables that are frequently loaded

Comment: You build indexes to match your performance-critical queries, not your table layouts. To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. And, if you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I guess I tried to give you all context on why I'm after the best index type with my process. i.e partially loaded large table (columns and rows) that will see daily transactions. I don't want the maintenance that comes with row indexes but would the large table with so many columns, would that impact the way a column index performs and stores its data. 
The queries arent complex as seen in my example,  I'm more concerned about applying the right type of index e.g Row, column, clustered or noncluster for my table that is part of the daily load.

Comment: Obviously, adding any index to a table of this size will take time. 
So I just want to choose the right type first time

Answer (score 0):

If this is your WHERE-clause pattern

```
Where Description IN ('Foo' ,'Bar' )
  AND Date > Dateadd(Month, -12, '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

an index on `(Description, Date)` will help it run efficiently.

But if this is your WHERE-clause pattern (I am guessing)

```
Where Description IN ('Foo' ,'Bar' )
  AND IsOpen = 1
  AND Date > Dateadd(Month, -12, '2021-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

then you need an index on `(IsOpen, Description, Date)`.  Read this: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

**Edit**

First: indexes get updated when tables get updated. That's the point.

Second: to design indexes, or even the type of index, an understanding of  your workload and access pattern is required.

Third: each table has exactly one clustered index. If the table has a defined primary key it's an index on that key. If the table has no PK, it's an index on some server-generated row id that's not visible to users.

Fourth: [columnstore indexes](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/columnstore-support-in-standard-tier-azure-sql-databases/#:%7E:text=Columnstore%20indexes%20are%20designed%20to%20be%20extremely%20efficient%20for%20queries%20which%20do%20scans%20and%20aggregations%20across%20millions%20and%20billions%20of%20rows%20of%20data) are, according to the documentation, "designed to be extremely efficient for queries which do scans and aggregations across millions and billions of rows of data." Again, you haven't told us what your workload looks like, so it's hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response.
The actual context in the index I'm fine with. 
Its a question around the current table size and what it will become as part of the process. 
Going forward would a column index be the best choice given the table size. 
So my views need to select all 350 columns but use those clauses of date and description. 
Any index on 32million rows is going to take a long time 
How will the index  perform once I have done maybe 10 days of daily loads